# C++ Throwing same error message from different places in code

Tags: c++, string, exception

I want to throw the same error from different places.
Here's an example:

```
int devide(int a,int b)
{
  if(b==0) {
    throw "b must be different from 0";
  }

  return 0;
}

int mod(int a,int b)
{
  if(b==0) {
    throw "b must be different than 0";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And in the main function:

```
int main()
{
  try {
    devide(1,0);
  } catch(char const* e) {
    cout << e << endl;
  }
  try {
    mod(1,0);
  } catch(char const* e) {
    cout << e << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now the output of the program is:

```
b must be different from 0
b must be different than 0
```

As you can see, the error by its nature is the same, but the **error message** is different. So what's the best practice that I can follow in this case, so it could be scalable? Let's say that I have 100 different types of exceptions, but when I throw an exception for `devisor to be different from 0` I want to get the same messege everywhere where the exception is thrown.

**EDIT:**
I was thinking for two options:

1. For every exception that I may throw I will define my own class that will inherit `std::exception`. Every exception I can put in `Exceptions.cpp`.
2. I can define one one `class MyException` that will inherit `std::exception` and in the constructor I will request an error string. And I can somewhere(I still can't think of where to put them) define static string constants that will describe the message. For instance, if I have already define `MyException` I can use it like this:

   ```
   int devide(int a,int b)
   {
     if(b==0) {
       throw new MyException(MyException::DEVISION_BY_ZERO);
     }
   }
   ```

Where `MyException::DEVISION_BY_ZERO` will be a string constant.

I think that the second approach requires less coding but doesn't seem really pretty to me.

**So is there a better aproach than the two above?**

Comment: Create your own exception type and throw that?

Comment: What @Nathan said and inherit from `std::exception`, or simply use [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but I was wondering if that is a good practice or if there is a better approach? I will edit my question to add more thoughts,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to create your own exception and throw that.

```
class Exception : public std::exception
{
    public:                
        template< typename... Args >
        Exception( const std::string& msg, Args... args );

        virtual ~Exception() throw ();

        //! Overrides std::exception
        virtual const char* what() const throw();

    private:
        //! Log the message_
        void log() const;

    protected:
        std::string message_;
};

template< typename... Args >
Exception::Exception( const std::string& msg, Args... args )
    : message_( StrFmt::format( msg, args ... ) )
{
    log();
}

class MyException : public Exception
{
    MyException() : Exception( std::string("b must be different from 0") )
}
```

If you further plan to exit the program on uncaught exceptions, it is possible to install a termination handler, where you rethrow the exception.

```
static void terminate()
{
    static bool tried_rethrow = false;
    try
    {
        if ( !tried_rethrow )
        {
            tried_rethrow = true;
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch ( const std::runtime_error& err )
    {
        std::cout << err.what();
    }
    catch ( const Exception& err )
    {
        std::cout << err.what();
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
    }
}
```

and in your main.cpp:

```
std::set_terminate( terminate );
```

That way it is possible to handle all uncaught exceptions at a single place.

Comment: Okay, but how does this solve the problem with different error messages? I can easily send different messages to the constructor of the `Exception` class.

Comment: I've added a customized exception.

Comment: Nice, I like the part with the template arguments. I couldn't found the `StrFmt` class/namespace but I got the idea. So I can put all my different error classes in a single unit `Exceptions.cpp` and when I need to throw exceptions just include that header and I'm ready?

Comment: Basically yes. StrFmt is just a placeholder to demonstrate that you can do some string parsing there.

Comment: By the way, +1 for the `terminate()` function!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a very good idea to throw primitive types as exceptions. The best way would be to use [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error), which is purposed for such cases.

If you want to distinguish the errors in your `catch()` blocks you can derive from that exception and initialize with the specific text:

```
class DivByZeroError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    DivByZeroError() : std::runtime_error("divisor must be different from 0") {}
    // Alternate constructor to provide a specific error message
    DivByZeroError(const std::string& s) : std::runtime_error(s) {}
}

class ModWithZeroError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    ModWithZeroError () : std::runtime_error("divisor must be different than 0") {}
    ModWithZeroError (const std::string& s) : std::runtime_error(s) {}
}

int main()
{
  try {
    devide(1,0);
    mod(1,0);
  } catch(const DivByZeroError& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  } catch(const ModWithZeroError & e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  } catch(const std::exception & e) { // Any other exceptions
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

As @CaptainOblivious mentioned in their comment, there's also [`std::invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) you can inherit from, if the parameter name is merely the only thing to change in the error message.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to derive from [`std::invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument)?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That would be an alternative solution yes, I just wanted to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer! Its simpler than @Trevir 's, but I will mark his answer as an `answer` because he proposed the same solution, but he added additional information that would be helpful for somebody else.

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev Mark whatever helped you best.

Answer (score 1):

What others are saying about not throwing primitive types, use a proper exception class, derive from `std::exception` ... is all good and correct.

Let's focus on you're "real" issue here:

> Let's say that I have 100 different types of exceptions, but when I
>   throw an exception for devisor to be different from 0 I want to get
>   the same messege everywhere where the exception is thrown.

Given properly typed exceptions, which is what you want, you sure as hell **do not** want the same exception message everywhere.

Let's look at the example from an answer:

```
class DivByZeroError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    DivByZeroError() : std::runtime_error("divisor must be different from 0") {}
    // Alternate constructor to provide a specific error message
    DivByZeroError(const std::string& s) : std::runtime_error(s) {}
}
```

The default constructor sure was convenient and easy to write. It's also 100% superfluous and redundant. It's a `DivByZeroError`, no need to put (only) *that* into the message again.

What you *really* want is an exception that *doesn't* have a default constructor, because you always want detailed information *what* went wrong *where* and *when*.

So, what you actually want is an exc. ctor that captures all that information and formats it on request in you virtual `what()` method of your `std::exception` derived class:

Paraphrased:

```
DivByZeroError(std::string const& function, std::string const& file, size_t line, optional<int> dividendValue = none, std::string const& message = "");
```

See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278949/why-do-many-exception-messages-not-contain-useful-details

Comment: Nice. I read the answer in the link that you gave and it makes really big sense! I can tell the difference by seeing standart exception messages in C++ and in Java(Android Studio). In Android Studio the exceptions are really descriptive and are always telling me the exact location and the exact reason of the exception. But strangely I've never thought that I can build exceptions like that. I completly agree with Mike Nakis in that answer. It's a topic that one must think of when writing any kind of code.